# Why this solution can't use a for-loop?

Tags: javascript

I was donig [Intersection of Two Arrays II](https://leetcode.com/problems/intersection-of-two-arrays-ii/) in leetcode.

I found solution in it and one thing that i don't understand is

Why this solution can't use for loop?

if i changed this line of code

```
while(p1 < nums1.length && p2 < nums2.length)
```

into

```
for(let p1=0,let p2=0;p1 < nums1.length && p2 < nums2.length;p1++;p2++)
```

the output will changed to only `[2]` not `[2,2]`

Why is that happened?

Request:
Given two arrays, write a function to compute their intersection.

> Input: `nums1 = [1,2,2,1]`, `nums2 = [2,2]`
>
> Output: `[2,2]`

Here is the JS code:

```js
   
      var intersect = function(nums1, nums2) {
       nums1.sort(cm);
       nums2.sort(cm);

       var p1 =0
       var p2 =0

       var res = [];

       while(p1 < nums1.length && p2 < nums2.length) {
           if(nums1[p1] === nums2[p2]) {
               res.push(nums1[p1]);
               p1++;
               p2++;
           } else if(nums1[p1] > nums2[p2]) {
               p2++;
           } else {
               p1++;
               }
            }
             return res;
         };
 
       var cm = function(a, b) {
            return a - b;
       }
       console.log(intersect([1,2,2,1], [2,2]))
```

Comment: The first two lines of code you posted are trivially *not* equivalent.

Comment: Are you still incrementing p1 and p2 inside the body??

Comment: ^^--That's why.

Comment: With a conditional increment of the indexes inside of the loop makes the two apparently equal loops totally different.

Comment: @RobertHarvey so...how to make my for loop equivalent?

Comment: `for(let p1=0,let p2=0;p1 < nums1.length && p2 < nums2.length;p1++;p2++)` shouldn't produce any output except a SyntaxError, I believe. It should be `for(let p1=0, p2=0;p1 < nums1.length && p2 < nums2.length;p1++, p2++)` in order to execute at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following for loop

```
for(let p1=0,let p2=0;p1 < nums1.length && p2 < nums2.length;p1++;p2++)
```

In this `p1` and `p2` always get increased in every loop. But in you you original code. There are increased conditionally

### Why for loop returns `[2]`:

When you increase `p1` and `p2` initially setting them to `0`. So it means
**in every loop the `p1=p2`. And hence it will compare the values on same indexes**.
In the following two arrays.

```
[1,2,2,1] 
[2,2]
```

Only the second `2` ([1,**2**,2,1] [2,**2**]) will be matched because both have same index `1`.

```
else if(nums1[p1] > nums2[p2]) {
   p2++;
} else {
    p1++;
}
```

You can also do that using `filter()` and `includes()`

```js
const intersect = (num1,num2) => num1.filter(x => num2.includes(x))
console.log(intersect([1,2,2,1],[2,2]))
```

Comment: But shouldn't while do the same thing?

Comment: @Jacky No inside while you are not increase `p1,p2` in every iteration. so they won't be same. In for loop both will be same

Comment: OK....thanks for answer!